# Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting the following error?

> ErrorException in AdsController.php line 69:
>   Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AdsController::pick_campaign() must be an instance of App\Websites, null given, called in /home/getad/dashboard.getad.ir/app/Http/Controllers/AdsController.php on line 256 and defined

line 69:

```
'protected function pick\_campaign(IlluminateHttpRequest $request, AppWebsites $website, $campaign\_tbl, $params = array( ))'
```

line 256:

```
' $eligible = $this->pick\_campaign($request, NULL, $campaign\_tbl, $p);'
```

Error 2

> 'QueryException in Connection.php line 631:
>   SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'details' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`user`, `type`, `amount`, `details`, `date`) values (1, click, 8, a:1:{s:5:"click";O:10:"AppClicks":22:{s:8:"_table";s:6:"clicks";s:10:"timestamps";b:0;s:11:"_fillable";a:9:{i:0;s:5:"token";i:1;s:8:"campaign";i:2;s:6:"banner";i:3;s:7:"website";i:4;s:2:"ip";i:5;s:4:"date";i:6;s:4:"fake";i:7;s:2:"os";i:8;s:7:"browser";}s:13:"_connection";N;s:13:"_primaryKey";s:2:"id";s:10:"_perPage";i:15;s:12:"incrementing";b:1;s:13:"_attributes";a:10:{s:5:"token";i:814927090;s:6:"banner";N;s:8:"campaign";s:2:"13";s:7:"website";s:2:"20";s:2:"ip";s:15:"109.125.175.129";s:4:"date";O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2019-06-02 15:12:32.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:11:"Asia/Tehran";}s:4:"fake";i:0;s:2:"os";s:7:"Windows";s:7:"browser";s:6:"Safari";s:2:"id";i:2464;}s:11:"_original";a:10:{s:5:"token";i:814927090;s:6:"banner";N;s:8:"campaign";s:2:"13";s:7:"website";s:2:"20";s:2:"ip";s:15:"109.125.175.129";s:4:"date";r:25;s:4:"fake";i:0;s:2:"os";s:7:"Windows";s:7:"browser";s:6:"Safari";s:2:"id";i:2464;}s:12:"_relations";a:0:{}s:9:"_hidden";a:0:{}s:10:"_visible";a:0:{}s:10:"_appends";a:0:{}s:10:"*guarded";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"*";}s:8:"_dates";a:0:{}s:13:"_dateFormat";N;s:8:"_casts";a:0:{}s:10:"_touches";a:0:{}s:14:"_observables";a:0:{}s:7:"_with";a:0:{}s:13:"_morphClass";N;s:6:"exists";b:1;}}, 2019-06-02 15:12:32))'

Comment: **Data too long for column 'details' at row 1** That´s why you are getting the error

Comment: @nacho tnx
 how can fix ?

Comment: Maybe the data you are passing to **details** it is too long (so you will need to sorten it) or the column details in your table it is too small so just give it more space.